# linux: truecrypt/veracrypt/luks/etc without /dev/loop*

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, kernel-modules

I'm using a linux system without any `/dev/loop*` devices and without the `loop` module compiled into the kernel, and I don't have the option of upgrading the system or kernel. I want to use `luks`, `truecrypt`, `veracrypt`, or something similar to create a file that gets mounted as an encrypted partition. Is there any way to do this without the kernel `loop` module?

My system doesn't even have a `loop` module to load via `modprobe`.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The loop device is the logical point to add disk encryption.

If you don't have a loop module, find the sources for the kernel version you are using, try to find or guess the configuration, and compile a loop module yourself.

Comment: I've already embarked down that exact path. I asked this question here in the first place to see if there might be an alternative to this approach. I guess not. Thank you.